# Automatic insertion of comment leader not working vim

Tags: vim

I can't seem to get the `formatoptions` to work in the general case for vim.

I have `filetype plugin on` and in many of the default plugins there's a line saying `setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql` and after reading the vim docs I saw that was where the automatic insertion of the comment leader was coming from. I liked this, but it wasn't happening in python, (because the formatoption line wasn't in the default plugin) so I put the line (except with `set fo+=crotl`) in my `.vimrc`.

It doesn't seem to have done anything, the comment leader is still not inserted in python (or bash which also doesn't have the line in the default plugin). 
I've also tried putting the line in my `.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` file (both as `setlocal` and `set`, and it hasn't done anything there either.

My question is - are there any options that will override this action that I should look out for? else,  what could be the reason it's not working?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I should note also: in the python buffers `:set formatoptions?` shows that the options have been set, they just don't work.

Comment: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` is the right place. You can do `:verbose set fo` to see what overwrites `fo`. Anyway, in Python, `#` is for single line comments so it's not supposed to be repeated on following lines and multi line comments, `"""`, typically don't have comment leaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out - The options were working, it was just that the comments were set with

```
set comments=...,b:#,...
```

and after looking that up, I found the 'b' means vim only counts the line as a comment if there is whitespace after the #, as I wasn't putting the space there, vim didn't count it as a comment and hence didn't apply the formatoptions set for comments.